# Can I delete a hardcoded value in a helmchart template?

Tags: charts, kubernetes-helm

I'm using a scaffolding chart that loads the templates from a dependency which I can't modify. Is there any possibility to remove the "-server" suffix defined in the deployment.yaml of the dependency?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: {{ .Release.Name }}-server
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overwrite the deployment YAML: Depending on the scaffolding tool you use, you could overwrite your own deployment.yaml file. In this case, you could make a copy of the original deployment.yaml file, remove the "-server" suffix, and use your modified version instead.